# Why are my auto-implemented properties working in ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, properties, automatic-properties

I'm using the auto-implemented properties syntax in the C# source files of my ASP.NET Web Application:

```
public int IdUser { get; set; }
...
this.IdUser = 1;
```

The **Target framework** of the project is **.NET Framework 2.0**. It compile and seems to run properly on a IIS Server with only ASP.NET 2.0 installed. I use Visual Studio 2010 to develop and compile.

I understood this syntax came with .NET 3.
Did I miss a setting somewhere in VS ? Can I expect trouble deploying the website on a IIS/ASP.NET 2.0 server ?

Comment: In case auto implemented ones the backing field is generated and pushed in by the compiler, so its very much like in case of a class you write with no constructors there is a default one pushed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auto-implemented properties were introduced in .NET 3.0 but are backwards compatible with 2.0. That's why you can run your code on 2.0 framework. Basically, it's just a syntactic sugar and the compiler actually generates a field for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jakub said, it is backwards compatible. For example you can also use implicitly declared variables (`var i = 1; //i is int`), though they were also only introduced in C#3.0!

Answer (score 1):

Automatically implemented properties works in .NET 2.0, but you won't be able to compile code in Visual Studio 2005. 
There is a list of 3.0 features and their compatibility with 2.0

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can only run .NET 3.0/3.5 features on a server that has just .NET 2.0 if you're using a web application or a precompiled site, rather than a Visual Studio "web site," since the latter is compiled on the server, where the former are compiled by Visual Studio.